# How should I fix the code in order to make the linear regression model using train data properly work?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, linear-regression

What I should do is to collect height and weight information from 5 people and use it as train data to learn the linear regression model in Colab.

There is an example code, so I fixed it, but it doesn’t work from the first place.

How should I fix the code in order to make the linear regression model using train data properly work? The code I have fixed so far is the following. The height and weight data below are the values I randomly chose.

```
import torch
import torch.optim as optim

# Defining data
x_train=torch.Float Tensor([48],[52],[60],[65],[73])
y_train=torch.Float Tensor([158],[162],[170],[175],[183])

# Hypothesis initiaization
W=torch.zeros(1,requires_grad=True)
b=torch.zeros(1,requires_grad=True)

# Defining Optimizer 
optimizer=torch.optim.SGD([W,b],Ir=0.01)

nb_epochs=1000
for epoch in range(nb_epochs+1):
  # Calculating H(x)
  hypothesis=x_train*W+b
  # Calculating cost
  cost=torch.mean((hypothesis-y_train)**2)
  # Learning with Optimizer
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  cost.backward()
  optimizer.step()


  # Log output every 100 times
  if epoch % 100 ==0:
    print('Epoch{:4d}/{}W:{:.3f},b:{:.3f}Coast:{:.6f}'.format(
        epoch,nb_epochs,W.item(),b.item(),cost.item()
    ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several minor mistakes in the code snippet, and actually you can read these from error messages

1. torch.Tensor(), and "torch.Tensor is an alias for the default tensor type (torch.FloatTensor)"
2. the data you feed in should be a Python list or sequence
3. Ir->lr (not ir, but Lr)
4. try lower learning rate (lr) for the nan problem
5. training with enough epochs

Given the least modification, it works

```
import torch
import torch.optim as optim

# Defining data
x_train=torch.Tensor([[48],[52],[60],[65],[73]])
y_train=torch.Tensor([[158],[162],[170],[175],[183]])

# Hypothesis initiaization
W=torch.zeros(1,requires_grad=True)
b=torch.zeros(1,requires_grad=True)

# Defining Optimizer 
optimizer=torch.optim.SGD([W,b],lr=0.0001)

nb_epochs=1000000
for epoch in range(nb_epochs+1):
  # Calculating H(x)
  hypothesis=x_train*W+b
  # Calculating cost
  cost=torch.mean((hypothesis-y_train)**2)
  # Learning with Optimizer
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  cost.backward()
  optimizer.step()


  # Log output every 200 times
  if epoch % 200 ==0:
    print('Epoch{:4d}/{}W:{:.3f},b:{:.3f}Coast:{:.6f}'.format(
        epoch,nb_epochs,W.item(),b.item(),cost.item()
    ))
```

reference:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html

Comment: Thank you soooooo much...... I really appreciate your kindness!!